# Binding Cocoa NSComboBox value to object

Tags: cocoa, binding, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, nscombobox

Assuming I have an `NSObject` subclass representing a country, e.g.

```
@interface CountryInfo : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *countryName;
```

My model contains an `NSMutableArray` of `CountryInfo`s. I want to bind the array to an `NSComboBox`. The combo box should display the country name, and allow the user to select a country.

So, I set up my .xib like so:

**CountryArrayController (NSArrayController)**

ContentArray

- Bind to: *File's Owner* > Model Key Path: *self.model.countries*

**NSComboBox**

Content

- Bind to: *CountryArrayController* > Controller Key: *arrangedObjects*

Content Values

- Bind to: *CountryArrayController* > Controller Key: *arrangedObjects* > Model Key Path: *countryName*

So far, so good. Now, how to bind the **Value** of the `NSComboBox`? The documentation states:

```
"An NSString or NSNumber that specifies the value of the NSComboBox."
```

What does this mean?
I note that I can bind this to an `NSString` on my model, and it will reflect the selected `countryName`. But I want to bind to the `CountyInfo` object itself! Whether directly, or through binding to the selection on my array controller: how can I set this up?

Comment: Have you tried using an NSValueTransformer?

Comment: Hi @macandyp, yes a NSValueTransformer would indeed work and I can get the same behaviour by binding on the string value and manually converting in code. It just seems bizarre that I have to write extra code to achieve this, and can't just bind to the object (which is what I am used to). Thanks!

Comment: I agree it's a bit weird. I know that if you bind to content, and not bind content values, it will invoke the description of your class to populate the strings for the combo box. I don't know if that helps you, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was approaching this wrong - the correct control to use was `NSPopUpButton` rather than `NSComboBox`.

`NSComboBox` has a different behaviour because it needs to support the scenario where the user directly enters text. `NSPopUpButton` is designed to only work with a predefined set of values and behaves as expected vis-a-vis it's "selection" bindings.

Answer (score 1):

This issue doesn't seem to have a simple solution, here is the one I found, implementing a NSArrayController category :

```
@interface NSArrayController( ComboBoxCompatibility )
@property(readwrite )NSString *firstSelectedObject;
@end
```

And for the getters and setters :

```
@implementation NSArrayController (ComboBoxCompatibility)
-(NSString *)firstSelectedObject
{
    return [[self selectedObjects] firstObject];
}
-(void)setFirstSelectedObject:(NSString *)firstSelectedObject
{
    NSUInteger idx = [[self arrangedObjects] indexOfObject:firstSelectedObject];
    [self setSelectionIndex:idx];
}
@end
```

You can then bind the value of the NSComboBox to your array controller's firstSelectedObject as soon as the objects in it implement copyWithZone: you can also modify the above code if the objects aren't strings but have a single property, "name" for example that you display in the combo box list by replacing [self arrangedObjects] with [[self arrangedObjects] valueForKey:@"name"] in the setter and [[[self arrangedObject] firstObject] valueForKey:@"name"] in the getter